# How to check for content overlay with bootstrap masthead

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

The page I'm working on with Bootstrap uses masthead navbar at the top. I understand if padding is not added, that the content will overlay the navbar. The content of each page is dynamic by ajax. Sometimes the content does not fill the page in which I desire it to remain centered vertical and horizontal. If content results (a table) grows, it begins to fill the page.

The problem is, If padding is added, the content ceases to be vertically centered when it doesn't fill the page and is pushed down by that many pixels. If padding is removed, it overlays the navbar as the content returned by ajax increases.

What would be the best way to check for overlay and then add padding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a different solution to this than what I was looking for, but it works for my purposes. After trying various combinations of padding and relative position adjustments, I found that adding padding to the bottom that is equal to padding on the top solved my problem and pushed an unfilled page equally in both directions, though, there is now empty space when a user scrolls to the bottom.